# parsley custom validator not triggering on dynamically generated fields (via ajax call)

Tags: parsley.js

Created an custom validator, and its initialised in the template where it is dynamically generated using the ajax call.
And the problem is that custom validator is not triggering in generated fields.
But if initialise that directly in html dom is working fine.
Does anyone knows about it.?

below shown is the custom validator:

```
 var iffRecursion = false;

//Validation for date_start
window.Parsley.addValidator('date_start', {
    requirementType: 'string',
    validateString: function (value, requirement, component) {
        console.log('date_start');
        if (!value) {
            return true;
        }

        var format = $(component.element).data('format');
        var date = moment(value, format, true);
        var endDateElement = $(component.element).closest('.row').find('.' + requirement);
        var endDate = moment(endDateElement.val(), format, true);

        if (!date.isValid()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (endDateElement.val() != '' && endDate.isValid()) {
            if (iffRecursion) {
                iffRecursion = false;
            } else {
                iffRecursion = true;
                $(endDateElement).parsley().validate();
            }
            return date.isSameOrBefore(endDate);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    priority: 256,
    messages: {
        en: 'The date is greater than End',
        ar: 'التاريخ غير صالح'
    }
});

//Validation for date_end
window.Parsley.addValidator('date_end', {
    requirementType: 'string',
    validateString: function (value, requirement, component) {
        console.log('date_end');
        if (!value) {
            return true;
        }

        var format = $(component.element).data('format');
        var date = moment(value, format, true);
        var startDateElement = $(component.element).closest('.row').find('.' + requirement);
        var startDate = moment(startDateElement.val(), format, true);

        if (!date.isValid()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (startDateElement.val() != '' && startDate.isValid()) {
            if (iffRecursion) {
                iffRecursion = false;
            } else {
                iffRecursion = true;
                $(startDateElement).parsley().validate();
            }

            return date.isSameOrAfter(startDate);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    priority: 256,
    messages: {
        en: 'The date is lesser than Start',
        ar: 'التاريخ غير صالح'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy parsley

```
$('form').parsley().destroy();
```

Then to re-init parsley when your ajax done

```
$('form').parsley();
```

Comment: still the custom validator is not trigerring.

Comment: @AnandPaul Could you share your customize?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, `Parsley` will auto detect inputs added dynamically, in particular whenever validating the form.

If your inputs are added dynamically and have specific triggers that need to activate before the whole form is validated, then you will need to initialize them. Easiest is probably `$('form').parsley().refresh()`

Comment: is there any function to solve recursion problem in validating?

Comment: inorder to validate the start date and end date that is generated dynamically